# AWS - Server to Server pub-sub

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, amazon-kinesis, aws-event-bridge

We do have a system that is using `Redis` `pub/sub` features to communicate between different parts of the system. To keep it simple we used the `pub/sub` channel to implement different things. On both ends (producer and consumer), we do have Servers containing code that I see no way to convert into Lambda Functions.

We are migrating to `AWS` and among other changes, we are trying to replace the use of `Redis` with a managed `pub/sub` solution. The required solution is fairly simple: *a managed broker that allows to publish a message from one node and to subscribe for its reception from 0 or more other nodes*.

It seems impossible to achieve this with any of the available solutions:

- [`Kinesis`](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/) - It is a streaming solution for data ingestion (similar to `Apache Pulsar`)
- [`SNS`](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/) - From the documentation, it looks like exactly what we need until we realize that there is no solution to connect a server (not a Lambda) unless with a custom HTTP endpoint.
- [`EventBridge`](https://aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/) - Same issue as with `SNS`
- [`SQS`](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/) - It is a queue, not a pub/sub.
- [`Amazon MQ / Rabbit MQ`](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/) - It is a queue, not a pub/sub. But also is not a SaaS solution but rather an installation to an owned node.

I see no reason to remove a feature such as subscribing from a server, this is why I was sure it will be present in one or more of the available solutions. But we went through the documentation and attempted to consume fro `SNS` and `EventBridge` without success. Are we missing something? How to achieve what we need?

### Example

Assume we have an API server layer, deployed on `ECS` with a load balancer in front. The API has 2 endpoints, a `PUT` to update a document, and an `SSE` to listen for updates on documents.

Assuming a simple round-robin load balancer, an update for `document1` may occur on `node1` where a client may have an ongoing `SSE` request for the same document on `node2`. This can be done with a `Redis` backbone; `node1` publishes on `document1` topic and `node2` is subscribed to the same topic. This solution is fast and efficient (in this case at-most-once delivery is perfectly acceptable).

*Being this an example we will not consider [WebSocket pub/sub API](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-websocket-apis-in-amazon-api-gateway/) or other ready-made solutions for this specific use case.*

##### Lambda

Subscriber side can not be a Lambda. Being two distinct contexts involved (the SSE HTTP Request one and the SNS event one) this will cause two distinct lambdas to fire and no way to 'stitch' them together.

##### SNS + SQS

We hesitate with `SQS` in conjunction with `SNS` being a solution that will add a lot of unneeded complexity:

- Number of nodes is not known in advance and they scale, requiring an automated system to increase/reduce the number of `SQS` queues.
- Persistence is not required
- Additional latency is introduced
- Additional infrastructure cost

##### HTTP Endpoint

This is the closest thing to a programmatic subscription but suffers from similar issues to the `SNS-SQS` solution:

- Number of nodes is unknown requiring endpoint subscriptions to be automatically added.
- Eiter we expose one endpoint for each node or have a particular configuration on the Load Balancer to route the message to the appropriate node.
- Additional API endpoints must be exposed, maintained, and secured.

Comment: Can you describe your requirements a bit more?  SNS to one or many SQS queues is a common pattern.  The subscriber can pick the queues they are interested in.  I'm not sure I understand your hesitation with a queue - you get a message when it's sent like a subscription but I may be missing something.